# Load asp.net control via AJAX

Tags: ajax, user-controls

This is my scenario:

many usercontrols, each of them contains many gridviews.

I want to (re)load a single gridview via an ajax call to get rid of postbacks and to improve performances and user experience. 
I don't want to rewrite tons of code so I just want to render that single gridview of that single control. 
`<br/>`
It means that if the gridview shows 4 fields and it has a bound server method it must be executed picking the rules from the .ascx.cs and the .ascx.

I cannot create a new instance of a gridview cause i need it to get created based on the .ascx rules.

I used this piece of code to create the grid and put it into the textwriter.

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView grid = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb))
{
    using (HtmlTextWriter textWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
    {
        grid.DataSource = ds;
        grid.DataBind();
        grid.RenderControl(textWriter);
    }
}
```

And it comes out like a normal grid as expected. But I don't need this; I need to generate a grid that is exactly the same as the one defined in the .ascx.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an `<asp:UpdatePanel>`.

Comment: Thanks man, that definetly solved my problem.
Sad thing is that passes through the whole page lifecycle, that slow things a bit =(

Comment: @Sballerio: ASP.Net Web Controls require the page lifecycle to function properly.  If you don't like that, consider using MVC.

Comment: Unfortunately i'm on already started project and changing the whole things from asp.net webforms to MVC (which i prefer) means we must rewrite everything =(((, and, as you might guess, this is not a viable solution. Even if it's slower, it's still acceptable. Thanks =)